# Artificial Biome in Batch

Tags: batch-file, artificial-intelligence

```
:Life

set /a R=%random%%%50+1
echo %random% >> %R%.bat
set /a t=%time:~6,-3%
If %t% geq 10 (
  set /a t=%t%-10
) else (
  set /a t=%t%+10
)
:wait
  If %time:~6,-3% neq %t% goto :Wait
:death
  set /a K=%random%%%50+1
  del /Q %K%.bat
:disease
  set /a D=%random%%%150+1
If %D% EQU 150 del /Q *.bat (
  goto Life
) else (
  If %D% EQU 150 echo On Error Resume Next > temp.vbs
  If %D% EQU 150 echo MsgBox "Disease Killed The Biome", vbInformation + vbSystemModal + vbOKOnly, "Life.exe" >> temp.vbs
  If %D% EQU 150 cscript temp.vbs
  If %D% EQU 150 del temp.vbs
goto Life
)
:EOF
```

So my issue is the timer engine. The counter itself contains 00–59 but the other is 0–59 so when the ticker hits a number and it has a value of 9 or less it'll skip them on the next passover because they don't have 09 (etc.), is there a way where I can set the code to other ticker to stay at 59 the whole time?

Comment: Ah... Uhm... in batch? Is it a contest or something?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to read, if you could format your code a little bit.

To solve your current problem, you could use the time to decimal trick.

```
set /a t=1%time:~6,-3%-100
```

Else you got problems with the times 08 and 09, because of the leading zero, it assumes it should be an octal value and fails.

And in the wait-loop you could use the same way

```
:wait
set /a now=1%time:~6,-3%-100
If %now% neq %t% goto :Wait
```

But to wait a time it is better to use the way,

```
ping localhost -n [sec]+1 > NUL
```

because the your way consumes the 100% cpu (one core).